# Did my Pi lockup or was it halted?

Tags: hardware, temperature, logfiles

I couldn't connect to my Pi this morning until I turned it off and on again. I did this at around noon, didn't record the exact time, thereafter it connected via ssh.

My sys.log state:

```
 Sep 18 23:59:32 raspberrypi ntpd[2127]: restrict: error in address '::1' on line 42. Ignoring...
 Sep 19 12:02:48 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2185]: (pi) CMD (sudo /usr/src/scripts/photosort1.py)
```

which sugests no activity between **23:59:32** and when i cycled the power at **12:02:48**

1) how can I tell if it is a `sudo shutdown -h now` or `sudo shutdown -r now` or a shutdown due to over temperature?

Comment: ntpd is the network time daemon, the second appears to be a cron job starting (python based, by name "photosort").  How does the Pi connect to the network, mine has a wifi dongle and 9 out 10 times when ssh is not answering I can still log in at the console, disable then re-enable wifi which seems to generally solve the problem.  However a few days ago, with slightly different symptoms, I had to reboot and never did figure out the problem.

Comment: My PI is running headless, and I'd have to pull the power plug and move it to get it to a console. I just wondered why I cannot see any activity in any of the logs between these two syslog entries.

Comment: And my point was, your pi may not have crashed or shutdown at all, it may just be unreachable.  My plan was for my pi to be headless as well, but so far I haven't gotten the system stable enough, specifically the instability centers around the network connection. Running it with a wired connection it remains stable and always available via ssh, but my final headless configuration will only have access to wifi.  At this point my next experiment is trying different wifi dongles.

Comment: This is strange. I get a big load of log entries by systemd upon issueing `shutdown` saying that it is stopping various services now. But if you cycled power shouldn't get you also lots of entries during boot up?

Comment: The log at 12:02:48 isn't the last log, it seems fine after that log. What is bothering me is there is no log activity between 23:59:32 and 12:02:48; when I must have turned it on again. I cannot understand why there are no logs between these times, I have cron running every min! I didn't shut it down, just wondered if it froze or was halted by the system.